# How to set dynamic height cells of UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, height

I created prototype `UITableViewCell` with a title and subtitle in `UITableView`. Contents in those cells have many word-lines. I'm trying to dynamically set the height of the cells.

The idea/method with sizeFont is deprecated with the latest SDK.

How to dynamically set the height of the cells in a simple way?

I'd be grateful for some advise or a link to a tutorial or even better some coding examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set height for `UITableViewCell` use [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) method of `UITableViewDelegate`.
To calculate `UILabel` height in iOS7 you have to use [boundingRectWithSize:options:context:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a) of `NSString`.
`boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` will give you a rectangle needed to draw your UILabel's text.
Try this code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString* string = yourLabel.text;
    UIFont* font = yourLabel.font;
    CGRect expectedLabel =
    [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                      attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }
                         context:nil];
    CGFloat verticalOffset = 10;
    return verticalOffset + expectedLabelRect.size.height + verticalOffset;
}
```